Movie about a girl who kills her sister and takes on her identity
The movie is about a girl, who has a popular sister in high school. For some reason I don't remember, I think she kills her popular sister and begins to imitate her, like wearing her clothes and especially using the same lip product as her sister. 
Later she becomes popular in school and befriends a new student. The new student finds out about her secret, so she tries to kill the new girl. It doesn't work and in the end everyone finds out the truth and the girl goes to prison. 
In the last scene she flirts with the officer so she can get the lip product her sister used before.

In "The in crowd" (2000), with Susan Ward as Brittany a popular girl who's sister is missing and the leader female of a group of rich girls,  who frames a new arrival Lori Heuring as Adrian, who is from an institution.
At first Brittany befriends the new girl Adrian before turning upon her after becoming jealous of Adrian. 
Brittany finds out Adrian's (new girl's) past and sets her up. This particular movie ends with an orderly bringing the now incarcerated popular girl (Brittany) some lipstick, actually a lip balm substance in small jar, as you have outlined above.

